# How to change the color of a focused EditText when using "android:Theme.Holo.Light"?

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-edittext

I Am using "android:Theme.Holo.Light" in my application, it gives blue as the Default color.
I want to have a `EditText` when focused like below.

[image]

By default it comes like this when applying `holo.light theme`.
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Holo Color generator for custom colors.

http://android-holo-colors.com/

You don't need to download all controls. Only these you want.

Comment: it doesn't change default state, only focused and activated

Comment: Hmm... wish it didn't generate the EditTexts with a lip on each end. I don't think the newer version of EditTexts have these.

Answer (score 7):

May this help you:

You will have to `create/modify` your own `NinePatch image` to replace the default one, and use that as the background of your `EditText`. If you look in your `SDK folder`, under your platform, then `res/drawable`, you should find the NinePatch image for the `EditText` focus state. If that's all you want to change, you can just pull it into Photoshop, or whatever image editing software you have, and change the orange color to a color of your choosing. Then save that into your `drawable folder`.

**For example:**

**edittext_modified_states.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_pressed" 
        /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused_blue" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_normal" 
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```