# Beautiful Stroked Text in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, custom-view, textstyle

I know how to stroke text using custom views(EditText or TextView) but I couldn't able to achieve something beautiful like this one, which is done using Photoshop. And yes, it has outer shadow too. [image: Stroked Text in Photoshop]

What I have done so far is adjusting stroke width and stroke join style. However, if I increase the stroke width, the stroke took place the whole text.
As far as I have searched, there is a library called [MagicTextView](https://github.com/m5/MagicTextView) but it also couldn't give the result like that above.

**Update**: I have tweaked things based on suggestion by @pskink. It works now. However I can't drag anymore. If I drag that EditText, there is some weird lines showed up like this. 
[image: Weird line above text view]

Here is the code:

```
@Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  final int x = this.getLeft();
  final int y = this.getBottom();

  mText = this.getText().toString();

  p.setStrokeWidth(30);
  p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
  p.setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND);
  p.setColor(0xffffffff);

  canvas.drawText(mText, x, y, p);

  p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
  p.setColor(0xff000000);

  canvas.drawText(mText, x, y, p);
}
```

Comment: call drawText twice with different colors and stroke width (or if you can have that fancy black shadow, call it three times)

Comment: @pskink Yes, I have tested that too. But it doesn't work out as expected.

Comment: @pskink added my current version of code. I don't have that version of code now but I have tested it and what I encountered was that I couldn't able to position the stroked version of text with drawText. My view is going to drag by users. It is not programmatically generated.

Comment: change Style.FILL to Style.STROKE and draw the thicker text first and then then normal text

Comment: @pskink updated the code. It works now but as I have said above, my view is draggable by users. Now, I couldn't able to drag it as expected. Something wrong in my positioning calculation?

Comment: you don't have to draw it four times,  draw it once with thick width and then second time with FILL,  as of drag,  i have no idea why it happens,  see if your onDraw is called during the drag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74698/discussion-between-sh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a few hours of tweaking, I have fixed the weird line issue stated in updated question. I think I should post here as the answer.

```
@Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mText = this.getText().toString();

    p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND);
    p.setShadowLayer(10, 1, 1, 0xcfcccccc);

    canvas.drawText(mText, 0, getLineHeight(), p);

    p.clearShadowLayer();
    p.setStrokeWidth(35);
    p.setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND);
    p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    p.setColor(0xffffffff);

    canvas.drawText(mText, 0, getLineHeight(), p);

    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    p.setColor(0xff000000);

    canvas.drawText(mText, 0, getLineHeight(), p);
    canvas.translate(xPos, yPos);
}
```

xPos and yPos are x and y values from `ACTION_MOVE` onTouch event. And We need to add the line height as a Y for the canvas text.

Answer (score 5):

> However, if I increase the stroke width, the stroke took place the whole text.

If the problem is that the stroke is centered, and you want it outside the text, see: [Android Paint stroke width positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309029/android-paint-stroke-width-positioning)

> You must precalculate the desired width and height according to your stroke.

I would suggest trying a very bold font.  In the image below, the **white** stroke would be centered on the **red** line (which would be the outline of each **black** letter).

[image]

In response to your **update**:

> If I drag that EditText, there is some weird lines showed up.

The line might be the result of focus on the EditText.  You can remove the focus explicitly: [Android: Force EditText to remove focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus)

Alternatively, you can style the focus (perhaps to be invisible, if it doesn't adversely affect the rest of your UI): [How to change the color of a focused EditText when using "android:Theme.Holo.Light"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672929/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-focused-edittext-when-using-androidtheme-holo-lig)

Comment: Adjusting width and height didn't solve too. Those strokes still take place the whole text.

Comment: Try using a very bold font.

Comment: Yes, I'm using bold font with android:textStyle="bold"

Comment: I mean the typeface itself should have thick characters.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I am already using roboto condensed. It is thick, right? Could you please elaborate more on your edited suggestion?