# How to draw outline stroke on text in TextView? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I need to draw outline stroke on text in MaterialTextView. I saw that it is not that easy to do in older questions.
(In this for example: [How do you draw text with a border on a MapView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723846/how-do-you-draw-text-with-a-border-on-a-mapview-in-android)).
Is something changed right now? If we need to set it programmatically, can anyone help me with Kotlin method for this and explain how to make it? I saw answers but I don't know where to create attrs.xml file I never used it before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Stroked Text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506643/beautiful-stroked-text-in-android)

Comment: @IvoBeckers not really. It's Java and i need to make standard outline not custom one

Comment: there isn't a standard as far as I know. And it being Java shouldn't matter. All Java can be easily converted to Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

You could define a rectangle shape in the `res/drawable` folder, let's call it `rect_border.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke android:width="2dp" 
        color="#000" />

</shape>
```

And use it as `android:background` for your `MaterialTextView`:

```
<MaterialTextView
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/rect_with_border" />
```

Comment: I need to use it for text :(